What clothing is included in Tajikstan's recent sumptuary law?
The government of Tajikistan recently passed a law imposing restrictions on the types of clothing that are legal within the country.
This law has generally been described as a "hijab ban," and it does indeed seem to have been primarily targeted at the hijab; however, its text is apparently more general and addresses wearing, buying, or selling any clothing "foreign to the national culture."
Which types of clothing are contemplated under the law? Does it also affect, for instance, burkas, turbans, European-style business suits, and so forth?

Such [broad/vague] laws in dictatorships (wich Tajikistan practically is) get interpreted however the police etc. likes, or at least how they perceive the supreme leader's wishes.

The law bans the use of "foreign clothing" — including the hijab. Instead, Tajikistan citizens are encouraged to wear Tajik national dress (EuroNews).
The law mostly targets the hijab, or Islamic head scarf, and other traditional items of Islamic clothing, which started coming to Tajikistan in recent years from the Middle East (ASIA-Plus).
Following this source, the ban is formulated in the Chapter 18 of the newly accepted Law of the Republic of Tajikistan on Regulation Celebrations and Ceremonies in the Republic of Tajikistan. I was able to find the complete document here. In the chapter 18, only the last paragraph (5) seems relevant:


Шаҳрвандон ва шахсони ҳуқуқии Ҷумҳурии Тоҷикистон уҳдадоранд
рукнҳои фарҳанги миллӣ, аз ҷумла забони давлатӣ ва пӯшидани либосҳои
миллиро риоя намоянд. Воридот, фурӯш, тарғиби либосҳои ба фарҳанги
миллӣ бегона, инчунин дар ҷойҳои ҷамъиятӣ пӯшидани чунин либосҳо манъ
мебошанд


That translates:


Citizens and legal entities of the Republic of Tajikistan are obliged to observe the elements of national culture, including the state language and wearing national clothing. The import, sale, and promotion of clothing foreign to national culture, as well as wearing such clothing in public places, are prohibited.



Did you try searching in Tajik?

@Obie2.0 thanks for the hint. I was able to retrieve the complete text of the document.
